# Loop through global substitution

Tags: regex, perl, while-loop

```
$num = 6;
$str = "1 2 3 4";
while ($str =~ s/\d/$num/g)
{
    print $str, "\n";
    $num++;
}
```

Is it possible to do something like the above in perl?  I would like the loop to run only 4 times and to finish with `$str` being `6 7 8 9`.

Comment: What do you mean by *only 4 times*? For example, if there 9 numbers in `$str`, you want to replace them all, of just 4 of them?

Comment: @GMB In this example the loop should only run 4 times

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the loop: the /g modifier causes the substitution to be repeated as many times as it matches. What you want is the /e modifier to compute the substitution. Assuming the effect you were after is to add 5 to each number, the example code is as follows.

```
$str = "1 2 3 4";
$str =~ s/(\d)/$1+5/eg;
print "$str\n";
```

If you really wanted to substitute numbers starting with 6, then this works.

```
$num = 6;
$str = "1 2 3 4";
$str =~ s/\d/$num++/eg;
print "$str\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could with the match operator.

```
my $new_str = '';
while ($str =~ /\G(.*?)\d/gc) {
   $new_str .= $1 . $num++;
}

$new_str .= substr($str, pos($str));
```

However, @TFBW's solution is probably what you want unless you're writing a tokenizer for a big parser. In a tokenizer, it would look more like:

```
# So we don't have to say «$str =~ all» over the place.
# Also, allows us to use redo.
for ($str) {
   /\G \s+ /xgc;   # Skip whitespace.

   if (/\G (\d+) /xgc) {
      # Do something with $1.
      redo;
   }

   ...

   last if /\G \z /xgc;

   die "Unrecognized token";
}
```